# To the right, to the left, now rotate

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, array

I was working on [HackerRank: Circular Array Rotation](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/circular-array-rotation) which is about coming up with an efficient algorithm for array rotations in right-ward manner.

> John Watson performs an operation called a *right circular rotation* on an array of integers. After performing one right circular rotation operation, the array is transformed from `[a(0), a(1), ..., a(n-1)]` to `[a(n-1), a(0), ..., a(n-2)]`.
>
> Watson performs this operation \$k\$ times. To test Sherlock's ability to identify the current element at a particular position in the rotated array, Watson asks \$q\$ queries, where each query consists of a single integer, \$m\$, for which you must print the element at index \$m\$ in the rotated array.
>
> The first line contains 3 space-separated integers, \$n\$, \$k\$, and \$q\$, respectively.
>   The second line contains \$n\$ space-separated integers, where each integer \$i\$ describes array element \$a(i)\$.
>   Each of the \$q\$ subsequent lines contains a single integer denoting \$m\$.

After vainly attempting to brute-force it (and the inevitable "time limit expired"), I came up with an algorithm that seems quite fast, as well as offering the flexibility of rotating by an arbitrary number of positions (which is, incidentally, why it is a lot faster than brute force).

I then decided to implement a complementary left-rotation function which works similarly (though I didn't manage to use list comprehensions for that one). As you can see from the code, they are coupled in that if a negative number is input as the number of positions to rotate, they call the other with its positive version. I did this for the sake of code reuse, but could it bite me back?

Here is a [working demo on repl.it](https://repl.it/E6rG/8) that demonstrates the results. Note I have tested it with small and large numbers, as well as negative numbers, and all appears to be working well.

```
def rotate_right(array:list, rotate_by:int = 1) -> list:
    '''
    Default behavior: 
        Given input [1,2,3] return [3,1,2]
    Supplying a rotate_by value other than 1 will increase the number
    of positions the values are moved towards the right by.
    '''
    if rotate_by < 0:
        return rotate_left(array, - rotate_by)
    array_length = len(array)
    while rotate_by >= array_length:
        rotate_by -= array_length
    return [array[i - rotate_by] for i in range(array_length)]


def rotate_left(array:list, rotate_by:int = 1) -> list:
    '''
    Default behavior: 
        Given input [1,2,3] return [2,3,1]
    Supplying a rotate_by value other than 1 will increase the number
    of positions the values are moved towards the left by.
    '''
    if rotate_by < 0:
        return rotate_right(array, - rotate_by)
    array_length = len(array)
    while rotate_by >= array_length:
        rotate_by -= array_length
    rotated = []
    for i in range(array_length):
        val_index = i + rotate_by
        if val_index >= array_length:
            val_index -= array_length
        rotated.append(array[val_index])
    return rotated


def main() -> None:
    # Testing code
    arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    rotate_by = 1
    print('Input array:', arr)
    print('Rotate by:', rotate_by)
    arr_L = arr_R = arr
    print('Rotate left:')
    for _ in range(len(arr)):
        arr_L = rotate_left(arr_L, rotate_by)
        print(arr_L)
    print('Rotate right:')
    for _ in range(len(arr)):
        arr_R = rotate_right(arr_R, rotate_by)
        print(arr_R)
```

Which will print the following to the output console:

> ```
> Input array: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
> Rotate by: 1
> Rotate left:
> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]
> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2]
> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3]
> [5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4]
> [6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> [7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
> [8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
> Rotate right:
> [8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
> [7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
> [6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> [5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4]
> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3]
> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2]
> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
> ```

With the above `rotate_right` function, the solution to the HackerRank challenge is very straightforward. It passes all test cases with no time-outs.

```
def main() -> None:
    values, rotations, queries = input().strip().split(' ')
    values, rotations, queries = [int(values), int(rotations), int(queries)]
    array = [int(n) for n in input().strip().split(' ')]
    array = rotate_right(array, rotations)
    # Final step, query the resulting array's indexes
    for _ in range(queries):
        index = int(input().strip())
        print(array[index])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you do not modify the list after it is created, one approach to efficient rotations is a simple wrapper class that holds the actual list and an offset denoting the position of the element that is considered to be the first element of a rotation. Now, "rotating" simply increases/decreases that offset value, which is done, of course, in constant time. Conversely, in order to get an \$i\$th element from the rotation, only a constant time overhead is present.

All in all, I had this in mind:

```
#!/bin/python3

import sys


class ListRotationWrapper:
    def __init__(self, the_list):
        self.the_list = the_list
        self.offset = 0

    def rotate(self, num):
        self.offset = ((self.offset - num) % len(self.the_list))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.the_list[(index + self.offset) % len(self.the_list)]


def main() -> None:
    values, rotations, queries = input().strip().split(' ')
    values, rotations, queries = [int(values), int(rotations), int(queries)]
    tmp_list = [int(n) for n in input().strip().split(' ')]
    rotable_list = ListRotationWrapper(tmp_list)
    rotable_list.rotate(rotations)
    # Final step, query the resulting array's indexes
    for _ in range(queries):
        index = int(input().strip())
        print(rotable_list[index])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's a really clever solution, thank you so much for enlightening me!

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend that you try to find a way to make `rotate_left` a list comprehension.
This is as it'll be simpler than you have now, and removes an if.
So I'd assume it to be faster too.

To do this you invert `rotate_right`, in both the indexing and the range. To get:

```
return [array[rotate_by - i] for i in range(len(array), 0, -1)]
```

But other than that your code seems pretty good. I personally would merge both `rotate_right` and `rotate_left` into one function `rotate`.

The biggest downside is it's \$O(n)\$ not \$O(k)\$, where \$n\$ is the size of the array, and \$k\$ is how much you want to rotate by.
Which is OK in this challenge, as you mostly want \$O(1)\$ indexing.

I'd also change how you change values to numbers, currently you're manually doing it, when you can use `map`.
And by using unpacking as you are with `split`.

```
values, rotations, queries = map(int, input().strip().split(' '))
```

---

As this is a programming challange I'd assume you don't want to use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-objects). (Gotta love batteries included!)
But going forward it would be better than your algorithm in *other* situations, performance wise.
This is as it's an efficient double ended queue. And so you can get `queue.rotate(1)` to be \$O(1)\$ and `queue.rotate(k)` to be \$O(k)\$.
Rather than it being based on the size of queue.

This can make your testing main:

```
from collections import deque

def main() -> None:
    # Testing code
    arr = deque([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
    rotate_by = 1
    print('Input array:', arr)
    print('Rotate by:', rotate_by)
    arr_L = arr_R = arr
    print('Rotate left:')
    for _ in range(len(arr)):
        arr_L.rotate(-rotate_by)
        print(arr_L)
    print('Rotate right:')
    for _ in range(len(arr)):
        arr_R.rotate(rotate_by)
        print(arr_R)
```

Comment: `deque` is very beautiful, but you are right in that I wanted to come up with my own algorithm for the challenge. Thank you!